# How to display downloaded PDF blob in an iframe?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, iframe, blob

I am using a `HttpRequest` to `GET` a PDF:

> http://www.example.com/path/some.pdf

I am using `response.getBodyAsBlob()` to store the data into a `ContentVersion`

I can view the PDF if I open the `ContentVersion` via the Lightning UI.

Then I want to display the PDF in an `iframe` so that the user can print from within a custom component.

```html
    <apex:page controller="PDFPreviewController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
        <body>
             <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64;{!PDF}" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
        </body>
    </apex:page>
```

Using controller:

```java
    public with sharing class PDFPreviewController {

        public String getPDF() {
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode([SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ID = :RecordID].VersionData);
        }

        private String RecordID {
            get {
                return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            }
        }
    }
```

But the PDF does not display.

I get this message in chrome:

> This site can’t be reached
> The web page at
> data:application/pdf;base64;JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8AdwBrAGgAdABtAGwAdABvAHAAZABmACAAMAAuADEAMgAuADQALQBkAGUAdikKL1Byb2R1Y2VyICj+/wBRAHQAIAA0AC4AOAAuADcpCi9DcmVhdGlvbkRhdGUgKEQ6MjAxOTA3MjIxOTAwMjlaKQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMyAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9TQSB0cnVlCi9TTSAwLjAyCi9jYSAxLjAKL0NBIDEuMAovQUlTIGZhbHNlCi9TTWFzayAvTm9uZT4+CmVuZG9iago0IDAgb2JqClsvUGF0dGVybi
> ........
> DEwNzUxIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTEwMjAgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAxNTExOCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDE1NDU3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMTUwOTcgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAovU2l6ZSAzMwovSW5mbyAxIDAgUgovUm9vdCAxOCAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjE2MzE5CiUlRU9GCg==
> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
> web address.
> ERR_INVALID_URL

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you add JS code?
This seems wrong `src="data:application/pdf;base64;{!PDF}"` , expression in quotes never worked for me.

Can you inspect iframe src if its fine?

Comment: Instead of `src="data:application/pdf;base64;{!PDF}"` , do something like
`src={pdfUrl}` and in js `pdfUrl = "data:application/pdf;base64;" + base64STringFromApex;`

Comment: In VF the properly way to write the `src` I believe is: `src="{! 'data:application/pdf;base64;' + PDF}"`

Comment: Try a different approach - make the apex:page with the `renderAs="pdf"` attribute, and then use `apex:includes` on that page in an outer page?

Comment: See [apex:include](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm).  Ex: `<apex:include pageName="MyPdfPage" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to alter your `getPDF()` method and prepend `data:application/pdf;base64,`

```
public String getPDF() {
        return  'data:application/pdf;base64,'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode([SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ID = :RecordID].VersionData);
    }
```

Markup:

```
 <iframe src="{!PDF}" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem was being caused by this: `base64;` where I should have been using `base64,` ... how frustrating!! thank you!!